# why am i getting error in console when having both .then and .catch function? but no error in console while having only .catch function?

Tags: javascript

```
let condition=false;

let p1=new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    console.log("p1 is pending");
    setTimeout(()=>{
        if(condition){
            console.log("p1 resolved");
            resolve("i resolved");
        }
        else{
            console.log("p2 rejected");
            reject("i rejected");
        }
    },3000);
});


p1.then((returned_val)=>{
    console.log(".then-> p1 returned :",returned_val);
})
p1.catch((returned_val)=>{
    console.log(".catch-> p1 returned :",returned_val);
});
```

I am expecting not to have an error in console, as there is the .catch function to handle it.
But this happens(no error in console) only while having the .catch function alone instead of presence of both .then and .catch function

Comment: `p1.then()` creates  a new promise and it has no `catch()` applied to it. You're only applying the `.catch()` to the original `p1`. And if `p1` rejects the `p1.then()` will also reject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two promise chain here:
`p1.then()`
and
`p1.catch()`

The rejection propagates through both chains, but there is no catch in the first one.

If you add a `.catch` there as well, the issue will be gone.

```
let condition=false;

let p1=new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    console.log("p1 is pending");
    setTimeout(()=>{
        if(condition){
            console.log("p1 resolved");
            resolve("i resolved");
        }
        else{
            console.log("p2 rejected");
            reject("i rejected");
        }
    },3000);
});
const errorHandler = (returned_val)=>{
    console.log(".catch-> p1 returned :",returned_val);
}

p1.then((returned_val)=>{
    console.log(".then-> p1 returned :",returned_val);
}).catch(errorHandler)
p1.catch(errorHandler);
```

And logged two times, as expected.